# SCILAB ODE Displays problem when solving Lotka-Volterra system

Tags: scilab

I am solving simple ODE equation with a code:

```
u=6;
z=2;
t=0:1:2000;
v0=0.04+0.001*u;
p0=0.03+0.001*z;
y0=[p0;v0];
t0=0;
b=0.2-0.01*u;
d=0.1;
c=0.4;
a=0.5;

 
function dx=f(t,x)
 dx(1)=b*x(1)-d*x(1)*x(2);
 dx(2)=c*x(2)-a*x(1)*x(2);
 x=[x(1);x(2)];
endfunction
y=ode(y0,t0,t,f);
```

Problem is, that using such t displays an error:

```
intdy--  t (=r1) illegal      
      where r1 is :   0.9560000000000D+03                                        
      t is not in [tcur-hu, tcur] = [r1, r2]
      where r1 is :   0.9553617168733D+03   and r2 :   0.9555070182087D+03       
intdy--  t (=r1) illegal      
      where r1 is :   0.9570000000000D+03                                        
      t is not in [tcur-hu, tcur] = [r1, r2]
      where r1 is :   0.9553617168733D+03   and r2 :   0.9555070182087D+03       
lsoda--  problems due to intdy. itask=i1,tout=r1
      where i1 is :          1                                                   
      where r1 is :   0.9570000000000D+03                                        
Illegal input detected (see printed message).

ode: lsoda exit with state -3.
```

I understand that the problem starts at t=956, but I don't understand how do I fight it. Is it related with value of the variable?

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong sign for the second equation (I suppose you are trying to solve the Lotka-Volterra prey-predator system). The correct right-hand side is

```
function dx=f(t,x)
 dx(1) =  b*x(1)-d*x(1)*x(2);
 dx(2) = -c*x(2)+a*x(1)*x(2);
endfunction
```

with a better time discretization, e.g.

```
t=0:0.1:200;
```

you will get the following result:
[image]

Comment: Actually the equation that I have written is correct, already in terms of what I am supposed to do - I just encountered a problem about time discretisation which I supposed is the problem with value going to infinity.

Comment: Nope. Ode uses adaptive intermediate time steps to reach default tolerance and matches the rough time steps you asked. Hence, taking a finer discretisation won’t change the behaviour of the approximate solution. It’s really amazing that your system is almost (up to this sign) the same as the Lotka-Volterra system....